# I can't run uwsgi as regular user

Tags: permissions, socket, uwsgi

I want to run uwsgi server as `www` user, but if I write:

```
uwsgi --socket $SOCKET --chmod-socket 666 --pidfile $PIDFILE --daemonize $LOGFILE --chdir $CHDIR --pp $PYTHONPATH --module main --post-buffering 8192 --workers 1 --threads 10 --uid www --gid www
```

A socket creation error occurs:

**Log:**

```
  1 *** Starting uWSGI 1.4.1 (64bit) on [Mon Dec 10 22:15:23 2012] ***
  2 compiled with version: 4.4.5 on 17 November 2012 23:31:14
  3 os: Linux-2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012
  4 nodename: autoblog
  5 machine: x86_64
  6 clock source: unix
  7 pcre jit disabled
  8 detected number of CPU cores: 2
  9 current working directory: /
 10 writing pidfile to /tmp/uwsgi_mysite.pid
 11 detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
 12 setgid() to 1002
 13 set additional group 1004 (files)
 14 setuid() to 1002
 15 *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
 16 your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 17 detected max file descriptor number: 1024
 18 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
 19 unlink(): Operation not permitted [core/socket.c line 109]
 20 bind(): Address already in use [core/socket.c line 141]
```

Comment: try posting your uWSGI configure and the log output. I would check your socket location. Something like /var/uwsgi is a good location.

Comment: Ok, updated with log

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for updating with your log.

According to your log file it says the address is already in use. The port you are trying to use is in use already.

look at `netstat -ntp` and make sure the port you are binding to is not already in use

Answer (score 0):

the most likely scenario is that you were previously running without the `uid` and `gid` arguments, thus the socket files are already existing and owned by root. `sudo rm /path/to/*.sock`, restart uwsgi, and you should be all set.

Comment: How do I find the location of the socket files?

Comment: I'd look in the .ini files. if you don't know where those are, use `lsof`